# Which design one-way ANOVA or 2-way ANOVA using SPSS?

Tags: anova, spss, heteroscedasticity

I have 2 drugs **A** & **B** with different 6 concentrations and for both drugs, at a specific concentration, the result is recorded (3 replicas),
so I am confused.

I have tried 2-way  `ANOVA`  but  `Levene's`  Test of Equality of Error Variances was **0.005**.
I have tried 1-way ANOVA in split file organized by sample, then the result was: drug **A** Levene's Test of Equality of Error Variances was **.031**, and drug **B** Levene's Test of Equality of Error Variances was **.064**.

Also, I tested normality with splitting, it is normally distributed.
My question is about Which design  `one-way ANOVA`  for each drug or  `2-way ANOVA`  including both drugs using `SPSS`?

Comment: What is your research question? Can you share (a link to) the data?

Comment: If you have a one-way design you can use Welch's ANOVA. For a two-way design with unequal variances you will have to resort to R and use `t2way` from WRS2. To me it looks like a 2 * 6 design. Don't know what you mean with 3 replicas.

Comment: Why do you mention SPSS in the question?   This site is about statistics.